# Can I run ASP.NET 4.0 on Windows XP IIS6?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, asp.net-4.0

Can I run ASP.NET 4.0 websites on Windows XP II6 or do I need Windows 7 with II7 in order to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run ASP.Net 4 applications on IIS 6, but some features will not be available like some of the additions to web publishing added to Visual Studio 2010 and the Auto Start feature to mention a few.

Of course don't forget to give it a different App Pool than the other applications using the other .Net versions.